# Java url-pattern all subdomains redirect

Tags: java, redirect, subdomain, url-pattern

is there any possibility in Java's web.xml of redirect all subdomains to one servlet?

For example:

```
<url-pattern>*.</url-pattern>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do that but I think you would like to define your URL pattern using `*.ext` or `*.*` as below:

```
    <url-pattern>*.*</url-pattern>
```

This is also used by some populare MVC frameworks such as `struts` where UL pattern

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

is mapped to Struts controller servlet.